# Detecting paste UITextView in textViewDidChange

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, paste, uitextviewdelegate

I am creating a `UITextView` for use as a rudimentary IDE. When the user pastes text (code) I am modifying it so that it fits inline (correctly indented) with the other text. However, I am also coloring the text (`attributedText`) using the `textViewDidChange` method. As a result when I paste text, it is first inserted then adjusted inline. The process looks a bit weird especially for a large chunck of text. I was wondering if there is a way for me to catch that the text is being pasted in `textViewDidChange` to avoid running attribute changes until the text is modified. Note that coloring attributes in the of the `textView shouldChangeTextIn` method is not possible as I am implementing some custom behavior through the interaction of the two methods and adding attributes needs to be done at the `textViewDidChange` stage.

**EXAMPLE SETUP**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if (text == UIPasteboard.general.string) {
        // MODIFY PASTABLE TEXT HERE

        // INSERT MODIFIED TEXT
        textView.replace(textRange, withText: newText)

        // PREVENT OLD TEXT FROM BEING INSERTED
        return false
    }
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    // MANAGE ATTRIBUTES
}
```

**WEIRD BEHAVIOR**

[image]

Comment: Could you do the formatting in the `shouldChangeTextIn:` method before returning `true`?

Comment: It's possible but would be a lot of work arounds :(